What do I put as my reason to leave?
As a minor last summer, I was illegally scheduled to work at my job. It was either resign or get fired for not being able to leave class in the morning to work. I'm applying for an internship and don't know what to put for my reason for leaving my job. What do I put?

There is quite a bit of context that could be helpful missing.  If you are studying at college and applying for an internship related to your course of study, it is quite possible that your previous random summer job won't even be a factor.  Your grades and references from teachers/professors will have much more weight.

Write, "to focus on coursework," if you have to write anything at all. All the other details just waste the reviewers' time.

If it is a real violation of laws, you should talk to your school's resources that are responsible for internships.
Definitely keep going to class, but let your internship point of contact at the school know what's happening and have them deal with the company.

I would say that I couldn't accommodate a rescheduling that conflicted with my educational goals.  This statement serves two purposes:

You communicate why you left
You also communicate what situation you're going to need in the prospective job, and there can be immediate conversation on whether this is a good fit rather than you wasting time if it won't be.

